# Writing to Unity's StreamingAssets folder at runtime, on Android?

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine

So...my goal is the following:

1. Download an .mp4 video with an http request.
2. Put it in the StreamingAssets folder in my Android APK, using www.bytes and File.WriteAllBytes().
3. Play it on an Android device, using the EasyMovieTexture movie plugin I bought.

However, I'm getting errors when I try to write to the StreamingAssets folder, at the following path:

```
jar:file:///data/app/com.catlard.testName-1.apk!/assets/ash.mp4
```

This is also the first value of _debugString in the PlaceMovieInStreamingAssets function below. Is it even possible to write to the StreamingAssets folder at runtime on Android? Here is the class I'm using to do this stuff. It stops on the WriteAllBytes call -- I know, because I've put print statements before and after, and that's where it's stopping.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class StartVideoFromWeb : MonoBehaviour {

    public string _movieFileName;
    public string _movieHTTPLocation;
    private string _debugString;
    private MediaPlayerCtrl _control;
    public float _mbFileSize = 16.7f;
    private string _movieLocationOnDevice;

    private float _prevProg;

    private WWW _movieWWW;

    public float _kbSpeed;
    public float _timeBetweenSpeedMeasurements = 1f;

    // Use this for initialization

    public IEnumerator Start() {

       yield return StartCoroutine("LoadMovie");
       PlaceMovieInStreamingAssets(_movieWWW);
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
       //PlayMovieInCtrl(_movieHTTPLocation + _movieFileName);
       PlayMovieInCtrl(_movieLocationOnDevice);

       yield return 0;
    }

    public void PlayMovieInCtrl(string path) {

       _control = GetComponent<MediaPlayerCtrl>();
       _debugString = _movieFileName + " was loaded into Ctrl";
       _control.Load(path);
       renderer.material.mainTexture = _control.GetVideoTexture();
       _control.Play();
       _debugString = "Attempted to play movie at " + path  + ".";

    }

    public void PlaceMovieInStreamingAssets(WWW www) {

       _movieLocationOnDevice = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + _movieFileName;
       //_movieLocationOnDevice =  Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + _movieFileName;
       _debugString = "Failed to write to path: " + _movieLocationOnDevice;
       File.WriteAllBytes(_movieLocationOnDevice, www.bytes);
       _debugString = "Wrote file to StreamingAssets folder.";
    }

    public IEnumerator MeasureSpeed() {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(_timeBetweenSpeedMeasurements);
       float tempMeasure = 0;//((_movieWWW.progress - _prevProg) * (_mbFileSize * 1024f)) * (_timeBetweenSpeedMeasurements /Time.deltaTime);
       _prevProg = _movieWWW.progress;
       if(tempMeasure > 0)
         _kbSpeed = Mathf.RoundToInt(tempMeasure);
       StartCoroutine("MeasureSpeed");
    }

    public IEnumerator LoadMovie () {
       string urlString = _movieHTTPLocation + _movieFileName;
       _movieWWW = new WWW(urlString);
       bool isLoaded = false;
       StartCoroutine("MeasureSpeed");

       while(!isLoaded && _movieWWW.error == null) {

         _debugString = "Movie " + Mathf.RoundToInt(_movieWWW.progress * 100f).ToString() + "%";

         if(_kbSpeed > 0)
          _debugString += " @ " + _kbSpeed.ToString() + "kb/sec";

         if(_movieWWW.progress == 1.0)
          isLoaded = true;
         yield return 0;
       }
       StopCoroutine("MeasureSpeed");

       if(_movieWWW.error == null)
         _debugString = "Movie loaded with no errors.";
       else
         _debugString = _movieWWW.error.ToString();

    }

    public void OnGUI() {
       GUI.Label(new Rect(0,0,700,100), _debugString);
       GUI.Label(new Rect(0,30, 400, 100), "Buffered: " + _control.GetCurrentSeekPercent().ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project assests (StreamingAssets ,RawAssets,etc..) are read only, you cant write anything there, instead write write to internal/external storage have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), if you prefer writing in c# i believe that you would use Xaramin framework

Answer (score 6):

Ahmad is correct, they are read only. You can however write to your `Application.persistentDataPath`.

I essentially did the same thing with streaming MP3s. This following script I wrote grabs data from internet (an mp3 file), and then persists it to the persistentDataPath and writes the bytes. If the file already exists it grabs from the local path instead of www.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class PlayMusic : MonoBehaviour {
    public string[] songs;
    public string currentSong;
    public WebClient webClient;
    public float Size = 0.0f;
    private int xRand;
    WWW request;
    byte[] fileData;

    IEnumerator loadAndPlayAudioClip(string song) {
        string path = song;
        currentSong = song;
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + xRand + "_song.mp3");
        if (info.Exists == true) {
            print("file://"+Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + xRand + "_song.mp3 exists");
            path = "file:///" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + xRand + "_song.mp3";
        }

        // Start a download of the given URL
        request = new WWW(path);

        yield return request;

            AudioClip audioTrack = request.GetAudioClip(false, true);
            audio.clip = audioTrack;
            audio.Play();
            Destroy(this);

    }
    void Start () {
        xRand = Random.Range(0, 11);
        StartCoroutine(loadAndPlayAudioClip(songs[xRand]));
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
       print("Size: "+Size+" bytes");
       if (request.isDone) {
               fileData = request.bytes;
               Size = fileData.Length;
               if (fileData.Length > 0) {
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + xRand + "_song.mp3", fileData);
                        print("Saving mp3 to " + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + xRand + "_song.mp3");
                }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ApolloSoftware I encountered the same problem as the OP and your solution works flawlessly on Android, but it doesn't work on iOS. Do you have any idea how to make it work on iOS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know what's funny. It used to work on iOS until about 6 months ago. I am assuming they changed something. Aside from allowing <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>  I'm not sure what else you could possibly do.

Comment: I fugured it out! On iOS, change "file:///" to "file://" (only 2 '/') and it works. Update your answer for future people asking the same question. I simply added a #if UNITY_IOS for that. Thanks for your answer!