# How to edit an XML file in Streamingassets from my hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I have a really frustrating problem with my app, I'm using Vuforia and I'm trying to edit and save an xml in streamingassets from runtime, however, I get the following exception: Unauthorizedaccessexception ... access to the path is denied.

I've tried to save both by simply using saving my XMLDocument to the path, this is where I get Unauthorizedaccessexception, but also tried but also the Windows.Storage namespace, and here i get an exception saying my path is invalid.

Here I get Unauthorizedaccessexception:

```
xmlDoc.Save(path);
```

and here I get path is invalid back.

```
var folderPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Vuforia");
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderPath);
StorageFile textFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("Warehouse.xml");
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(textFile, str);
```

Using `var folderPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath);` to save the file with `xmlDoc.Save(path);` works perfectly. I can't do this though because of Vuforia only being able to access image targets in StreamingAssets(right?). So does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong, what can I do to gain access to the StreamingAssets folder or change where the folder is located that Vuforia uses?

Comment: are you on Android?

Comment: No, I'm deploying to hololens

Comment: StreamingAssets are read only. So you have to copy your files to somewhere under persistentDataPath. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188742/writing-to-unitys-streamingassets-folder-at-runtime-on-android

Answer (score 3):

On HoloLens I also had trouble.

You might want to rather try [`StreamWriter.WriteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writeasync) in combination with [`File.Open(string, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open#System_IO_File_Open_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_).

It seems to me that the HoloLens requires the `File.Open` with the [FileMode.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode), [FileAccess.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileaccess) and [FileShare.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare).

Also I would suggest to use [`Path.Combine(string, string, string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_System_String_)

Something like

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamAssetsPath, "Vuforia", "Warehouse.xml");

using(var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)) 
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWritet(fileStream))
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync(textFile);
    }
}
```

this usually worked for me in the past.

---

Note however that I honestly never tried to write to the `streamingAssetsPath` from a build, only within the UnityEditor in editor scripts. And in builds only to the persistent data path. **Possible that the streaming assets are read only in a built app.**

---

*Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I used the code you suggested but still got Unauthorizedaccessexception. Might there be any other way to modify the access to a file?

Comment: As i said I'm not sure if you actually can write to streamingassets in a built app. Possible that it becomes read-only after building.